# path() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and trying to set up my first app (home page) and I am currently following a tutorial. When i added in a new path into my urlspatterns list, and link it to the correct function, I get TypeError: path() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Below is my code:
App Directory
urls.py

```
from argparse import Namespace
from importlib.resources import path
from unicodedata import name
from django.urls import re_path
from . import views

urlspatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index') # this is the main site path (home page)
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

# This is form the home page
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Hey, Welcome</h1>')
```

project directory
urls.py

```
"""cheatChecker URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('homapage/', include('homepage.urls'))
]
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'homepage',
]
```

Error that I get
File "D:\Capstone_project\Capstone_project\cheatChecker\homepage\urls.py", line 8, in 
path('', views.index, name='index') # this is the main site path (home page)
TypeError: path() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

I tried to takeout name and the error that i get is "valueerror empty module"

Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: have you tried deleting the whole multi-line string at the top of urls.py?

Comment: You imported path from the wrong lib. It should not be `importlib.resources`, but `django.urls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are importing the wrong path function you should import it from django.urls

```
from django.urls import path
```